# sed - replace value to use quotes where needed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have 100+ jinja template files with 0-k occurrences of "value: ..." string in each of them. The problem is that some of the files are using:

```
value: something
```

some of them:

```
value: 'something'
```

and some of them:

```
value: "some other thing"
```

I need all of these to look the same, to use double quotes. I thought I'd do it with sed:

```
sed -i 's/value: ['"]?(.*)['"]?/value: "\1"/g' *.j2
```

but as you can see I'm quite horrible with sed and the past 2 hours only made me want to break my keyboard with the nonsense error messages I'm getting, like: unterminated `s' command and such.

Sample input:

```
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: '/bin/echo'
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: Hello World
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

from this I need to get:

```
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: "/bin/echo"
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: "Hello World"
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of your files. When present, is the closing quote _always_ the last thing on the line? Do you have other quotes that need to be unchanged?

Comment: Do you need the `"value"` in quotes as well? Best thing is give us a sample of input and expected output

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that you have literal single quotes in a `sed` program enclosed in single quotes. This will not work. You can replace the literal single quotes in your regular expression with `\x27` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added a sample input and the expected output.
@AdminBee: I already tried escaping pretty much everything... I'm really miserable with sed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need to use the two forms of quotes (`"'`) in the expression, things get tricky. For one, in your original attempt the shell identifies this `'s/value: ['` as a quoted string: the latter quote is not preserved.

In these cases, rather than having a headache, you can simply put the Sed commands in a file. Its contents won't be subject to the shell manipulation.

**`quotes.sed`**:

```
# (1) If line matches this regex (value: '), 
# (2) substitute the first ' with " and
# (3) substitute the ' in the end-of-line with ".
/value: '/{
  s/'/"/
  s/'$/"/
}
# (4) If line matches this regex (value: [^"]), 
# (5) substitute :<space> for :<space>" and
# (6) append a " in the end-of-line.
/value: [^"]/{
  s/: /: "/
  s/$/"/
}
```

```
$ sed -Ef quotes.sed file
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: "/bin/echo"
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: "Hello World"
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your `sed` call is two-fold

- You have literal single quotes as part of your regular expression `['"]` in a `sed` program enclosed in single quotes. This will not work as single quotes inside single quotes cannot be escaped. You can represent them as `\x27`, however.
- The `... (.*) ...` syntax is extended regular expression syntax for having `(` and `)` mean "capture group" by default. Your should either use the `-E` option of `sed`, or define the capture group as `\(.*\)` to use [basic regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (but then you would need to replace the `?` with something like `\{0,1\}`, too).

The following worked in my tests:

```
sed -E 's/value: [\x27"]?([^\x27"]*)[\x27"]?/value: "\1"/' input.j2
```

Comment: With this exact command I get: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS. I tried a similar version with [\'"]? already which yield the same error.

Comment: Can you state the `sed` version in your question text? It works on GNU `sed` 4.2.2 with the example file you provided.

Comment: GNU sed 4.2.2. My OS is RHEL7 if that makes any difference.

Comment: What happens if you use `sed 's/value: [\x27"]\{0,1\}\(.*\)[\x27"]\{0,1\}/value: "\1"/'`?

Comment: Nice, it now works flawlessly! Am I right that hexadecimal representation with `\x` is a GNU Sed extension?

Comment: Still gives the same error. @Quasímodo's solution works perfectly.

Comment: @Displayname are you using macOS perhaps? Or Cygwin? Or something else that is not Linux?

Comment: @Quasimodo I'm not sure. I have often found `\047` as recommendation, but that one didn't work for me, whereas `\x27` did (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24509931/12231187) e.g.).

Comment: No, it's an actual RHEL7 OS. Okay, technically a Hyper-V VM on Windows 10 but still..

Comment: @Displayname it's hard to believe you get the error message you say you do from the script in this answer. I can see how you'd get an error with the "similar version" you mentioned in your comment. Please copy/paste the script from this answer exactly as-is and try it again. I'm thinking you either removed the `-E` or changed it to `-e` or you escaped the round brackets.

Comment: @EdMorton I used copy+paste, I checked it again, still yields the following error and I copy this from the terminal now: "Invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS"

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(\s*value:\s*)(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] "\"" gensub(/[\047"]/,"","g",a[2]) "\""} 1' file
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: "/bin/echo"
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: "Hello World"
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

otherwise Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/value:/{hd=$0; sub(/:.*/,": ",hd); gsub(/[^:]*: *[\047"]?|[\047"]$/,"");  $0=hd "\"" $0 "\""} 1' file
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: "/bin/echo"
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: "Hello World"
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl6)**

A gentleman by the name of Larry Wall posted this neat quoting tip on the "perl6-users" mailing list (perl6-users@perl.org). See Tip #8 at the NNTP link below:

```
~$ env re="\'" raku -ne 'say $0 if m/ <?after value\:\s >  \"? <{ %*ENV<re> }>?  (.+?) \"? <{ %*ENV<re> }>? $$ /;'  jinja.txt
｢/bin/echo｣
｢Hello World｣
｢PATH｣
```

The code above shows the correct match. So all that's needed is to run the code below:

```
~$ env re="\'" raku -pe 's/ <?after value\:\s >  \"? <{ %*ENV<re> }>?  (.+?) \"? <{ %*ENV<re> }>? $$ /"{$0}"/;'  jinja.txt
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: "/bin/echo"
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: "Hello World"
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

Want to make your escaping more readable? Don't want to play with ENV variables as above? Then just spell out your quoting characters (also from Larry Wall's Tip #8 at the NNTP link below):

```
~$ raku -ne 'say $0 if m/ <?after value\:\s >  \c[QUOTATION MARK]? \c[APOSTROPHE]?  (.+?)  \c[APOSTROPHE]? \c[QUOTATION MARK]? $$ /;'  jinja.txt
｢/bin/echo｣
｢Hello World｣
｢PATH｣

~$ raku -pe 's/ <?after value\:\s >  \c[QUOTATION MARK]? \c[APOSTROPHE]?  (.+?)  \c[APOSTROPHE]? \c[QUOTATION MARK]? $$ /"{$0}"/;'  jinja.txt
- param:
  name: Command
  type: String
  value: "/bin/echo"
- param:
  name: Args
  type: String
  value: "Hello World"
- param:
  name: Something
  type: EnvVar
  value: "PATH"
```

HTH.

https://raku.org/
https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2020/07/msg9004.html